# How to run a thread endlessly in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have two threads A and B. The solution that I wish to achieve is, thread A should run endlessly consuming some events from a broker. Thread B must get activated only when there are a specific number of messages consumed, let's say 10. Thread A must run endlessly consuming messages and thread B must get activated when thread A gets 10 messages and perform an action and die, and start again when the next set of 10 messages comes in. The way I tried to work this is:

```
def threadA():
    #an action

def threadB():
    #an action

readThread.start()
sleep(10)
emailThread.start()

readThread.join()
emailThread.join()
```

By this way, the threads ends once a single loop ends. And also I didn't add the logic for starting the thread B after it gets 10 messages, which is also the part that I'm not able to achieve.

Comment: Start `threadA` from your main code.  Every time IT handles 10 events, have it start a `threadB`.  You can `detach` it, since you don't care when it finishes.

Comment: How can I detach a thread?

Comment: Sorry, I used the C++ word for it.  In Python, set `t.daemon = True`.

Comment: I have did that. But even after that, the threadA ends after a single loop

Comment: Did you put a `while True:` inside `threadA()`?  It's hard to read with the font so small

Comment: you mean inside the run function of threadA?

Answer (score 2):

`while True:` must be present inside a thread to use it endlessly. And in order to execute B when thread A has been executed 10 times, a queue or deque that can exchange data between threads must be used.(The use of global variables is not recommended, and it is recommended to use deque rather than queue.) Finally, a thread can only be started once, so it's a good idea to keep running unless you're declaring a new thread. Therefore, threadB also puts `while True:`. (It is always recommended to use `daemon=True` for threads that run endlessly with `while True:` to reduce memory wastage.)

```
import threading
from collections import deque

def threadA(dqu):
    count = 0
    while True:
        if count == 10:
            dqu.append('do B')
            count = 0
        #an action
        count += 1

def threadB(dqu):
    while True:
        if dqu:
            msg = dqu.popleft()
            if msg == 'do B':
                #an action

dequeAB = deque()
readThread = threading.Thread(target=threadA, args=(dequeAB,), daemon=True)
emailThread = threading.Thread(target=threadB, args=(dequeAB,), daemon=True)
readThread.start()
emailThread.start()
while True:
    pass
```

Comment: If I just print a statement in the places where you added a comment 'an action', it doesn't work, the program provides different outputs every time and mainly the program ends, it does not stay endless.

Comment: @Suganth This is because the main thread executes the last line and exits, killing all threads. try adding ```while True: pass```. (I edit my answer, you can find the way)

Comment: `while True: pass` will drain your laptop's battery pretty quickly; try `while True: time.sleep(10000)` if you want to block forever without spinning the CPU

Comment: But that would block it for 10000 seconds only right, I want it to be blocked forever

Comment: This is a 10000 second shutdown every 10000 seconds, so this is a great way to minimize your battery and shut it down forever.

Comment: Oh that's great. I thought it will only shutdown for 10000 seconds. I was stupid, I didn't think it will happen again anyway. Thanks man.